# Unity won't build to Android (almost blank project test)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I have tried to test-publish my beginner very basic project core on Android from Unity and it failed every time I tried.. As a beginner I'm not quite sure why.

I tried to open and close Unity, publish to other platforms (OpenGL, Windows). I have downloaded Unity plug-in for Android (SDK included).

Code editor is Visual Studio (C#).

I will be glad for any help or comment :)

[Logs here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18CmIBvIIAuiG88esqz2POeY0psuwErRc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: well it keeps saying repeatedly `Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.` ...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by myself.

I chose to "export" to my device (phone) and not to "build" or "build and run" options.. and that made the difference for some reason. Works fine now.